# Use Python to find the resolution of image with any image file extension without using any non-default library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can I find the resolution of an image with *any* extension without using any module that is not part of Python's standard library (except perhaps PIL)?

Comment: `Image.open("filename").size` ? `Image` can be imported from `PIL`, they support a [ton of file formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html)

Comment: @GammaGames Great! Thanks a lot, that worked out well. Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting image resolution in Python pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829577/setting-image-resolution-in-python-pillow)

Comment: Er... no it doesn't... I want to read the image resolution, not set it. And anyway, @GammaGames's comment's already helped me out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444548/how-do-i-get-the-picture-size-with-pil resolution and dimension is not the same

Comment: Hmm... a mistake in my understanding, perhaps, but GammaGames's answer was still what I was looking for

Comment: das Gut ........

Comment: Zero-dependency on non-default libraries as requested here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035508/2836621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an image's resolution with the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package:

```py
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("filename") as image:
    width, height = image.size
```

You can find more in the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.size)

As pippo1980 pointed out, this is for the dimensions of the image and not for the image's resolution. For completeness, here's how to get an image's *resolution*:

```py
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("filename") as image:
    xres, yres = image.info['dpi']
```

Comment: that is image dimension in pixel not resolution

Comment: @pippo1980 You're right, I tend to use the terms interchangeably but just in case others come across the issue I've updated the answer

Comment: Actually I didnt know about xres and yres !!! Thanks  see here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517814/using-pillow-to-find-dpi never thought about non-square pixels